# If $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$, then show that: $\sin A = \sin B \cos C + \cos B \sin C$

Tags: trigonometry

Here is the question :

> If $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$, then show that: $\sin A = \sin B \cos C + \cos B \sin C$.

I don't really have any clue where to start.

The only thing I would think to do would be to change $\sin A = \sin B\cos C + \cos C\sin B$ to $\sin (B+C) = \sin B\cos C + \cos C\sin B$. But I'm not sure if that is even useful.

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT :

Here is my working, can someone comment and confirm that this working is correct.

> We want to show that
>   $$
> \sin A=\sin (B+C).
> $$

Since 
$$
\space A+B+C = 180^\circ, \space A =180^\circ-(B+C)
$$
And 
$$
\space \sin A=\sin (180-A),
$$
then
$$
\sin A=\sin(180-(180-(B+C))
$$
$$
\sin A=\sin(180-180+(B+C))
$$
so
$$
\sin A=\sin(B+C).
$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It is better, though, to use $\pi$-radiant notations : $$ A+B+C=\pi$$ since in fact it is $$\sin(\pi-A)=\sin(A)$$ (180° is a **notation** for a given angle, but if you want to compute the sinus of it, the value to give to the sinus function (for that very angle) is $\pi$).

Comment: @Netchaiev I'm just going off the question I was given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
A+B+C=180\,\,\,\ \text{and}\,\,\,\,\sin(A)=\sin(180-A).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you check over this answer :

$\sin A= \sin (B+C)$  

Since $A + B + C = 180$, $A = 180 - (B+C)$  

And $\sin A = \sin (180 - A)$

$\sin A = \sin (180-(180-(B+C))$

$\sin A = \sin (B+C)$

Comment: @Conal This is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sin A = \sin (180°-B-C)$$

and

$$\sin (180°-x)=\sin x$$

Answer (score 0):

You already know that
$$
\sin B \cos C + \cos B \sin C = \sin(B+C).
$$
Therefore to prove that the left side of that identity is equal to $\sin A,$ it is enough to prove that the right side is equal to $\sin A.$ Thus the problem is to prove that
$$
\sin(B+C) = \sin A
$$
when you know that $A+B+C=180^\circ.$

Suppose the problem had been phrased as follows:

> Prove that if $A+B+C= 180^\circ$ then $\sin(B+C) = \sin A.$

In that case, neither $B$ nor $C$ is mentioned except in the sum $B+C$. Thus one can just let $D=B+C$ and forget about the fact that it's a sum, so the problem becomes this:

> Prove that if $A+D=180^\circ$ then $\sin D = \sin A.$